# Laravel showing markers in map from database

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am trying to show multiple markers from the database. But I am getting this error.

**Controller**

```
$events_happening_today=Events::where('start_date','=',date('Y-m-d') )->get();
$events_happening_today_count=Events::where('start_date','=',date('Y-m-d') )->count();
```

**Blade**

```
<script>
   function initMap() {
      var pos = {lat: 40.7128, lng: 74.0060};
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
      {
          zoom: 7,
          center: pos
      });
      for (i = 0; i < {{$events_happening_today_count}}; i++)
      {
          marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng({{$events_happening_today->latitude}}, 
                                          {{$events_happening_today->longtitude}}),map: map
       });
   }
}
</script>
```

**Error:**

> "Property [latitude] does not exist on this collection instance.

What should I do ? Am I doing it right ?

Comment: latitude property is not available in your Event model. does your event table have a column named latitude ?

Comment: @KanonChowdhury yes it has

Answer (score 0):

take 2 hidden inputs for latitude and longitude and for loop through it

```
@foreach($events_happening_today as $index=>$event)
<input type="hidden" id="lat_{{$index}}" value="{{$event->latitude}}" />
<input type="hidden" id="long_{{$index}}" value="{{$event->longtitude}}" />
@endforeach
```

for total count

```
<input type="hidden" id="total" value="{{$events_happening_today_count}}"/>
```

inside your script :

```
<script>
        function initMap() {
            var pos = {lat: 40.7128, lng: 74.0060};
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),
                {
                    zoom: 7,
                    center: pos
                });

            var total= parseInt(document.getElementById("total"));
            for (i = 0; i < total ; i++)
            {
                var lat=Number(document.getElementById("lat_"+i));
                var long=Number(document.getElementById("long_"+i));
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long),
                    map: map
                });
            }
        }
</script>
```